# Holding "Backspace" deletes only one character

Tags: 14.04

I don't know what I've done, but when I press and hold the key "Backspace" it just deletes only 1 character and stops. This is everywhere: in the console, Chrome, Text editors.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Is it only for the Backspace button ?
Have you tested your keyboard in other OS/PC ?
try to clean it up if the prob is persists

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `unity-control-center keyboard` and make sure keyboard repeat is enabled

or use `gsettings` to change value:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat true
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thanks! Had the same issue on Ubuntu Budgie 17.10

Comment: Glad to hear it still works

Comment: On 16.04, my was still enabled when I opened unity-control-center.  Simply unchecking and rechecking solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

The `xset` utility can be used to enable keyboard repeat. It works on the X.org level, so should override whatever the distribution is doing wrong.

To enable keyboard repeat, execute:

```
xset r on
```

For details, see [man xset](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/xset.1.html).

> It worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: just needed this command on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: "xset r on" also works with kali linux thanks to @varshneydevansh